# Internal JQuery document.ready to override an external one

Tags: jquery, overriding, external, internal, document-ready

I'm having a generic external file `document.ready()` with a `$('form').submit()` action, however, I want to override this action from within one of my files which include that `document.ready()`.

In other words, I want my internal `document.ready()` should do additional checks on the form before the `$('form').submit()` works.

Comment: Ok. But why do you need more than one document.ready(). PROTIP use `$.fn.ready()` its for the coolkids

Answer (score 0):

In your internal code you could try to stop the immediate propagation of the `submit` event:

```
$(function () {
    $('form').on('submit.immediate', function (event) {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
});
```

Then when you want the form to be able to submit again you can just remove this binding:

```
$('form').off('submit.immediate');
```

This will only remove the `submit` event handler attached with the `immediate` namespace, so other bindings will remain intact.

It's entirely possible I'm not quite understanding your problem. You may just need to bind an event handler to the form(s) that stops their ability to send until you have decided to send them:

```
$(function () {
    $('form').on('submit.immediate', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

`event.preventDefault()` will stop the form(s) from being submitted, then you can remove this event handler once you want to submit the form.

Note that `.on()`/`.off()` are new in jQuery 1.7 and in the cases used above are the same as `.bind()`/`.unbind()`: http://api.jquery.com/on, http://api.jquery.com/off

Docs for `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`:

> Keeps the rest of the handlers from being executed and prevents the
>   event from bubbling up the DOM tree.

*Source: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/*

Comment: I see that there are multiple ways to accomplish this task. But is it a flexible and efficient way to interrupt the eventhandling? Wouldn't it be better if you build your structure to prevent this kind of stuff? You could use callbacks or publish and subscribe to keep it clean and extensible

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you're doing. You need to post code for more insight. It's a good idea to bind events using a namespace like I did in my answer so you can remove specific event handler if you want. If you can remove the event handler you don't want to use, then that's really the best way, otherwise just interrupt it's ability to function, as long as you aren't doing this on tons of elements at once you won't notice any performance decrease.

Comment: Good answer, thank you. But im wondering if you can make sure, that the event is interrupted in the right time. As far as i can see, you will fire both events, the submitting one and the interrupting one at the same time. But i never heard of `submit.immediate` is it a self declared namespace, or a jquery directive that gets triggered just before the normal `.submit()`?

Comment: That's just a namespace added to the event handler so you can remove the specific handler without affecting others. Since I don't know what order your code is running in, the best way for you to see if you can interrupt the `submit` event is to try it out.

Comment: Im not the inquirer of this question. I just asked you to explain your approach. The questioner uses `.submit()` which is a shortcut for `.trigger("submit")` not `.on("submit", callback)`. The problem i  see is that the trigger may be executed before the prevention.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be:

```
var formActions = new function() {

    this.form = $('form');

    this.doStuff = function() {

        //Do Stuff  

        //If you got more than one form
        $.each("this.form", function(i, v) {
            //PlayWithForm
        })

        this.submit();
    };

    this.submit = function () {

        this.form.trigger( "submit");
    }

}

$.fn.ready(function() {
    formActions.doStuff();
})
```